# How do I add a 'like us on facebook / twitter' button

Tags: html, facebook-like, twitter-follow

I have a blog-type website and I would like to add a line of buttons at the bottom of every page, saying 'like us on facebook' and 'follow us on twitter'. How would I go about doing that? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am in no way affiliated with these people but they have a very simple solution and offer free analytics, i havent used them in a blog but i have implemented them on my web pages:

[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com)